# Linux command line utility to determine mp3 bitrate?

Tags: linux, command-line, mp3

Is there a command-line utility to determine the bitrate of an mp3 file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get all ID3 meta-tags including the bitrate from [**exiftool**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool):

> ExifTool is free software used for
>   reading, writing, and manipulating
>   image, audio and video metadata. It is
>   platform independent and is both a
>   Perl library and command-line
>   application. ExifTool is a popular
>   tool to incorporate into different
>   types of digital workflows and
>   supports many types of metadata
>   including Exif, IPTC, XMP, JFIF,
>   GeoTIFF, ICC Profile, Photoshop IRB,
>   FlashPix, AFCP and ID3, as well as
>   manufacturer-specific metadata of many
>   digital cameras.
>
> Starting with version 7.79 (June 20,
>   2009), ExifTool added read/write
>   support for Adobe InDesign files
>   (.IND, .INDD, .INDT), and ability to
>   geotag with KML files.

The command you want is:

> $ exiftool -AudioBitrate File.mp3  
>   Audio Bitrate                   : 128000

Running the command without any arguments gets you all the tags. It is [cross-platform](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), and works for most multimedia types. This is available via the **libimage-exiftool-perl** package on Ubuntu.

Comment: This also looks useful, and I'll give it a try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

**[file](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29)** is able to identify the bitrate of constant-bitrate (CBR) MP3s, and is probably already installed on your machine, even if your distro is one of those that avoids installing an MP3 decoder.

However, it only looks at the beginning of the file, so it will not get the true bitrate for variable-bitrate (VBR) or average-bitrate (ABR) MP3s, but only that of the first frame, which may be misleading.

Comment: I believe this is only accurate for constant rate (CR) mp3s, not variable rate (VBR).

Answer (score 8):

mpg321 should display this info when the -t switch is used. It is actually a command-line player, but -t should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 5 years old, but Google finds it, and it's excellent advice.

```
exiftool -AudioBitrate File.mp3
```

gives much better information in an easier-to-read format. e.g.:

```
======== 15-Is This Thing On .mp3
Audio Bitrate                   : 320 kbps
======== 16-Run.mp3
Audio Bitrate                   : 320 kbps
======== 17-Good Old Days.mp3
Audio Bitrate                   : 320 kbps
```

Comment: ...true, but isn't this already mentioned in nagul's answer? (Please see http://superuser.com/about if you figured this is a "regular forum".)